# Start-Process is not working in Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, invoke-command, start-process

```
$upgradeInvoke = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

        try {
            Shutdown.exe /r /f /t 1200 /d p:4:2 /c "Triggerd Reboot Timer for 20 minitus"
    
            $arguments = "/s", "/v`"/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress`""
            $process = Start-Process -FilePath $using:setupFullPath -ArgumentList $arguments -PassThru -Wait -Verb runas
            Write-Output $process.ExitCode
        }
        catch {
            Write-Output "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }

} -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Stop
```

I'm Trying to install VMTools in a remote machine after disabling UAC, The Invoke is working and I could see User32 Event logged in EventViwer for reboot. But Start-Process is not getting triggered. The same script is working when any other user is just logged in via RDP or Direct Console. It looks weird, doesn't it? Moreover, its working fine with Windows Server 2012 R2, 2016 and 2019 Standard. It's not working with Windows 2022 Standard.

Comment: So the _exact same_ command works on older Windows server versions? Note that you shouldn't need `-Verb RunAs`, because remoting sessions are implicitly elevated. A pitfall re `Start-Process` in remote sessions is that the launched process is terminated when the session ends. You could try synchronous direct invocation instead, e.g. `cmd /c "\`"$using:setupFullPath\`" /s /v\`"qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress\`""` - `$LASTEXITCODE` will then reflect the exit code.

Comment: It has failed with the below log.

MSI (s) (F8:D8) [12:29:16:693]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (s) (F8:D8) [12:29:16:693]: Running product '{AF174E64-22CF-4386-A9EC-73F285739998}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (s) (F8:D8) [12:29:16:693]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PRODUCTLANGUAGE property. Its value is '1033'.
MSI (s) (F8:D8) [12:29:16:693]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (F8:D8) [12:29:16:693]: Product: VMware Tools -- Installation failed.

Comment: Is there no additional error code? Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-error-messages, `1708` simply generally indicates that the "Installation operation failed."

Comment: Note that the implicit elevation I mentioned only occurs if the user identity used for remoting is in the Administrators group on the remote machine - by default, that is a prerequisite for being able to use a given identity for remoting, but through explicit configuration non-admin users can be enabled for remoting too. A simple test for whether a given remote session is elevated is to run `net session` in it: it'll fail with `Access denied` if non-elevated.

Comment: It has returned with exit code 0 which means it’s completed. But when I checked the upgrade wasn’t happened. Then I enabled logging and got the previously shared logs

Comment: Hello mklement0,

I've tried it this way and it's working somehow, I'll check with other Windows Versions and let you know the status. I'm still wondering why the start-process is not working here.

$arguments = "/s /v", "/qn", "/l" ,"C:\temp\log.log", "REBOOT=ReallySuppress"
cmd /c "`"$using:setupFullPath`"$arguments" - $LASTEXITCODE
Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE

Comment: You should not put code in a comment, but you can use [edit] to add that text (formatted) to your question.

Comment: @SpicerLabs: Glad to hear the `cmd` approach works, though `"/s /v"` doesn't look right - I assume they should be separate array elements. Also, these arguments don't match what you tried with `Start-Process`.

Comment: @mklement0: The 'cmd /c' method didn't worked in Windows Server 2012 R2, Hence I've clubed both commands. 

``` 
$arguments = "/s", "/v", "/qn", "REBOOT=ReallySuppress" 
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c "$using:setupFullPath" $arguments" -Wait Write-Output 
$LASTEXITCODE
```

This is working in all the Windows versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'cmd /c' method didn't work in Windows Server 2012 R2, Hence I've clubed both commands. `$arguments = "/s", "/v", "/qn", "REBOOT=ReallySuppress" $process = Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c "$using:setupFullPath" $arguments" -Wait Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE` This is working in all the Windows versions